# Angualrjs- redirect from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers.  I would like to use the other controller based on a dependancy value.  I am not able to set this at the $route level.  How can I essentially do this on in the main controller: Is this even possible?

```
angular.module('app').controller('Controller1', ['importantService', function(importantService) {

    if (importantService.getValue) {
       // Use this other controller Controller2 instead
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you really need to entire controller or just some code from it?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils The whole controller

Comment: What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your 2 controllers in directives and have an ng-if in the template switch between the two, something like:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, importantService) {
  $scope.importantValue = importantService.getValue;
});

app.directive('myFirstComponent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/same/url/for/both',
    controller: function() {/*...your controller 1*/}
  };
});

app.directive('mySecondComponent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/same/url/for/both',
    controller: function() {/*...your controller 2*/}
  };
});
```

and in your template

```
<div ng-if="importantValue === 1"><my-first-component></my-first-component></div>
<div ng-if="importantValue === 0"><my-second-component></my-second-component></div>
```

probably not the most orthodox solution but it will do what you're asking.